# /proc/currentime does not exist

Tags: linux, macos

I am reading about jiffies in linux kernel. In one of the related example in the book Linux Device Driver, the author use

```
head -8 /proc/currentime
```

to print out some time information.

However this file is not present in my linux installation (kernel: 2.6.32-131.6.1.el6.x86_64).

Why is it the case? Is it because the file path is no longer valid, or it is a distribution feature thing?

It is not present in OSX too. What would be an equivalent in OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not part of Linux. The *only* references to `/proc/currenttime` I could find are Linux kernel programming courses – along the lines of "Write a kernel module that creates a `/proc/currenttime` file..." It could be that your book has the same task and the author is simply referring to a previously written module.

Comment: As an aside, Mac OS X does not have `procfs` at all, never mind `/proc/currenttime` although there are ways to get it (e.g. http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter11/procfs/ ).